# Regex. Specify that a character can't be there

Tags: regex

I want to recognice a code line and my problem is with the start of a code line. I don't know how to make my regex recognice when a instruction is next to something that is not part of the instruction.

my regex:

```
int [A-Za-z_]+ ?= ?\d ?(\+|-) ?\d *;
```

In this example the regex recognise the instruction but it is wrong.

```
asdsaint var = 2+2;
```

it recognice the "int var = 2+2;" but the int is next to "asdsa" then this is not good.

I want my regex to only recognice an instruction when the instruction is like:

```
(int var = 2+2;) With nothing before the isntruction
(    int var = 2+2;) With n white space before.
(int var = 2+2;int var = 2+2;) With the ";" character before.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend a `\b` to require a word boundary before `int` like so:

```
\bint [A-Za-z_]+ ?= ?\d ?(\+|-) ?\d *;
```

Depending on the regex flavor used you can also use a negative zero-width lookbehind like so:

```
(?<![A-Za-z_])int [A-Za-z_]+ ?= ?\d ?(\+|-) ?\d *;
```

Also, to be more tolerant on whitespace, you might want something like this:

```
(?<![A-Za-z_])int\s+[A-Za-z_]+\s*=\s*\d\s*([+-])\s*\d\s*;
```

Comment: @anubhava In most (if not all) C-style languages, the `-` is not part of the allowed identifier characters, so that I think that this is working as wanted. If the OP has a more precise specification I'll be happy to adjust my regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
(^|\s+?|;)int var\s?=\s?\d+?\s?[+-]\s?\d+?(?=\s|;|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/WitW8W/1